# How can I tell a string is encoded from db.model_to_protobuf

Tags: google-app-engine

I use db.model_to_protobuf for my AppEngine project, I wonder if is there a way to tell a string is encoded from db.model_to_protobuf? I have no time to read the source code, can anyone give me a favour?

Thanks~

Comment: seems start with j5j\x06, end with \x0c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, yes - the protocol buffer encoding format is documented [here](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/encoding.html). In practice, this is a terrible idea: you should use metadata to identify the format of your data, and decode it based on that, not based on trying to guess the content type.